# AOL mail rejected using smtplib

Tags: python, mail-server, smtplib, aol

I'm using `smtplib` to send email via AOL account, but after successful authentication it gets rejected with following error.

```
reply: '521 5.2.1 :  AOL will not accept delivery of this message.\r\n'
reply: retcode (521); Msg: 5.2.1 :  AOL will not accept delivery of this message.
data: (521, '5.2.1 :  AOL will not accept delivery of this message.')
```

Here's explanation for this error.

```
The SMTP reply code 521 indicates an Internet mail host DOES NOT ACCEPT
incoming mail. If you are receiving this error it indicates a configuration
error on the part of the recipient organisation, i.e. inbound e-mail traffic
is being routed through a mail server which has been explicitly configured
(intentionally or not) to NOT ACCEPT incoming e-mail.
```

Recipient mail (in my script) is valid (gmail) address and after this debug message mail gets rejected.

```
send: 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version:    1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nSubject: My reports\r\nFrom: myAOLmail@aol.com\r\nTo: reportmail@gmail.com\r\n\r\nDo you have my reports?\r\n.\r\n'
```

Here's short version of code:

```
r_mail = MIMEText('Do you have my reports?')
r_mail['Subject'] = 'My reports'
r_mail['From'] = e_mail
r_mail['To'] = 'reportmail@gmail.com'

mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.aol.com", 587)
mail.set_debuglevel(True)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(e_mail, password)
mail.sendmail(e_mail, ['reportmail@gmail.com'] , r_mail.as_string())
```

Is this some kind of permission problem because I'm successfully sending same email with Yahoo account without any problems?

Comment: Are you able to send emails from the same AOL account ? I mean by using the web browser. This issue is something on AOL side.

Comment: @ρss thanks! I'll have to check what's wrong with this account. I've just tried another account and it worked.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned it is some problem with that specific account or with the AOL. The python script has no issues! Maybe you have violated the terms & conditions of the AOL email services or maybe this AOL account was spamming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that AOL doesn't allow relay access by default or you have not configured it manually. The error you get says that aol doesn't have recipient you want to send message. In this case if you want to send email to gmail account try to connect to gmail SMPT server instead of AOL.

Change smpt server to `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` for example and turn off authentication.

Comment: I think the OP wants to send an email from AOL account using AOL server to a Gmail account. I think the issue the OP is facing has something to do with the AOL server or email services not the Gmail.

Comment: Yea, but OP can simply set up `From` header to his AOL account, the only issue of this method is that major ESP's require DKIM and SPF headers in your message, without it message will likely hit junk mail folder. If this does not matter OP can try the solution i described.

Comment: Gmail no longer allows this kind of connection. They make everyone go through their PAID API now.

Answer (score 0):

Was running into `5.2.1 : AOL will not accept delivery of this message.` from the AOL SMTP relay myself. What I ended up needing was valid From and To headers in the MIME message body, as opposed to just the SMTP connection.

In your particular case there could be any number of reasons for getting this 5.2.1 bounce. The postmaster.aol.com site has some helpful tools to diagnose, as well as some pretty vague documentation for this specific error message. In my case I ended up packet sniffing the SMTP messages that my Thunderbird email client was sending vs. the Python script, and eventually spotted the  difference.

### postmaster.aol.com documentation:

https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes

**AOL will not accept delivery of this message**
This is a permanent bounce due to:

- RFC2822 From domain does not match the rDNS of sending server.
- RFC 2822 FROM address does not have an A record and is not a valid domain.
- IP has a poor reputation and mail is sent to multiple recipients.
- There are multiple From address in the mail headers and the IP reputation is poor.

### My Python function for sending mail through smtp.aol.com:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def genEmail(user, passwd, to, subject, message):
    smtp=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.aol.com',465)
    smtp.login(user, passwd)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = user # This has to exist, and can't be forged
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    smtp.sendmail(user, to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```